# WPF Expander Listview over Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, expander

I'm having an odd issue with the Expander control in WPF.  I have a ListView to select some items using the expander and everything within that control works fine.  However, the ListView appears over Textbox control and when the expander is collapsed, the part of the Textbox that would be hidden by the ListView cannot be interacted with by the mouse.  When my cursor is over the part of the TextBox that is not hidden, I get the expected text-entry cursor; when it is over the other portion, I get a simple mouse pointer.

XAML for the Expander is below:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="DestPathTextbox" Margin="10,217,275,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="24" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Expander x:Name="FolderListExpander" Header="Folder List" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="140.51" Margin="0,192.52,275,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" Expanded="FolderList_Expanded" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <!--Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>-->
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <ListView x:Name="FolderListview" MouseUp="FolderSelected_OnChanged"/>
        </Border>
    </Expander>

</Grid>
```

Comment: What TextBox control? There's no TextBox here. Please provide a XAML sample that demonstrates the issue you're having. That includes the *common parent* of both controls. The sample should be a XAML subtree I can paste into Visual Studio and see it work as you describe. The relationship between the controls must be clear. Please confirm that if you paste the sample into a new XAML file, *you* can see the issue reproduced.

Comment: The TextBox is just a standard Textbox, nothing special about it at all.  The header for the Expander is above TextBox and the ListView expands downward to obscure it when expanded.

Comment: If you understand this issue well enough to diagnose it without an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please do so. I'd look at the inexplicable `RenderTransformOrigin` first, and I'd think about using conventional WPF layout techniques in the future. Good luck.

Comment: Updated with the XAML for the entire Window and verified that it exhibits the same issue in a completely new Window.  Removing the `RenderTransformOrigin` had no effect on the issue whatsoever.

Comment: That's about what I thought I might see. Here's the deal: The Expander has a fixed height, whether it's expanded or not. Set its Background property to Red to illustrate that. Since it appears after the TextBox, it's above the TextBox in the Z order (the Z axis is a notional line from the screen to your eyeball). Since you're positioning these things in a Grid by Margin, they don't do proper flow layout as they should. Set the height of the Expander's *content*, and let the Expander size itself. And use grid rows and columns instead of Margins to place controls.